# Batch move file with using regex to new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm not dev, I'm just looking for get code.

my folder:

```
default-0.png
default-0@2x.png
default-1.png
default-1@2x.png
default-2.png
default-2@2x.png
default-3.png
default-3@2x.png
default-4.png
default-4@2x.png
default-5.png
default-5@2x.png
default-6.png
default-6@2x.png
default-7.png
default-7@2x.png
default-8.png
default-8@2x.png
default-9.png
default-9@2x.png
...
```

I want move files with filename "**@2...**" only and any file extension to "new folder".

```
default-0@2x.png
default-1@2x.png
default-2@2x.png
default-3@2x.png
default-4@2x.png
default-5@2x.png
default-6@2x.png
default-7@2x.png
default-8@2x.png
default-9@2x.png
...
```

I trying use regex: `(^.+@2.+.$)` see check [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qsu3Tj/1) for full match text.

I tried my code and doesn't work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir /b | findstr /r "(^.+@2.+.$)") do (
    md "new folder"
    move "%%~f" "moved folder"
)
Echo done
pause
```

anyone help me, what am i wrong?

UPDATED: thanks for @develc (answered) and @Mofi (edited)
This worked, perfect number of my files matched regex.

```
md "new folder"
move "*@2x*" "new folder"
```

ANOTHER METHOD:
This worked but 0.1% can't move cause can't detect to filename has comment like `example@2x - if comment.png`. thanks for answered by @Hackoo

```
@echo off
MD "new folder">nul 2>&1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *@2*') do (
    move "%%~f" "new folder"
)
Echo done
pause
```

Comment: Would be "dir \*@2\*" be enough detection for you? Then pipe that to your move.

Comment: What would happen if you checked `dir *@2*` as was suggested? And `new folder` is a different directory from `moved folder`

Comment: how i do my move after pipe?

i tried: `dir "*@2*" | move "moved folder"`

Comment: `my folder` is current folder,
`moved folder` is renamed instead new folder,
im sorry, my bad. i mean move `my folder` to `moved folder`

Comment: The pipe before `findstr` needs to be escaped with a caret (`^|`) to tell `cmd` that it's part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be used something like this:

```
md "new folder"
move "*@2x*" "new folder"
```

In batch files, `*a` means *everything that ends with* **a**; `b*` means *everything that starts with* **b**; `a*b` means *everything that starts with* **a** *and ends with* **b**; `a?b` means *everything that starts with* **a**, *has one character between* **a** *and* **b** *and ends with* **b**. So `*` is a wildcard for *everything* and `?` is a wildcard for *every character*.

See: [MS-DOS and Windows Wildcard Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/indexsrv/ms-dos-and-windows-wildcard-characters)
 on Microsoft's documentation site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

```
 @echo off
 MD "new folder">nul 2>&1
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /f %%f in ('dir /b *@2*') do (
     move "%%~f" "new folder"
 )
 Echo done
 pause
```

Comment: I wrong double quoted like "dir /b *@2*" say The system cannot find the file specified.

Thank you for helpful!

Comment: updated, i tested this 99% moved but some few can't move, error say `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 1):

There can be used also:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe . "new folder" *@2x.* /MOV /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS >nul
```

The entire directory tree to the specified destination folder – in this case the subdirectory `new folder` in current directory – is automatically created by **ROBOCOPY** on not existing before moving all files in current directory matched by the wildcard pattern `*@2x.*`.

Run in a command prompt window `robocopy /?` for help on this command.

See also:

- [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- Microsoft documentation for the [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)
- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))

Comment: I never heard this robocopy. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this (based on @develc's answer)

```
@echo off
echo Setting up . . .
set "file=%temp%\d-file%random%.txt"
echo "d" > "%file%"
echo Starting the copy process . . .
xcopy /D /V "*@2*" "new folder" 1>nul < "%file%"

if errorlevel 0 (
    echo Copying files completed successfully.
    echo Starting to delete old files . . . 
    del /Q "*@2*" || (echo Deleting files failed. && echo on && exit /b 1)
    echo Deleting files completed successfully.
    @echo on
    @exit /b 0
)

echo Copying files failed.
@echo on
@exit /b 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally your regex syntax seem to be correct. But when you check "findstr" documentation the plus (+) character is not in accepted list :)

Findstr doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr

You can try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
MD "new folder">nul 2>&1
for /f %%f in ('dir /b ^ | findstr /r "(^.*@2.*$)"') do (
    move "%%~f" "new folder"
)
Echo done
pause
```

Comment: I know but I just looking code because I'm not good make code.
btw I tried this but doesnt work.